# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SLCT'

Tags: python, import

*English is not my mother tongue, so there might be some grammatical errors in my question.

Sorry about that.*
I git clone a project from github to my VScode. When I wanted to run demo code, a "ModuleNotFoundError" occured. I was confused about this error. Because I checked module and it did exit, I also haven't install same name module before. 
Here is the project-tree of the project.(Only parts including "SLCT" are given)

```
source code
└─ logparser_root
   ├─ benchmark
   │  ├─ SLCT_benchmark.py
   ├─ demo
   │  ├─ SLCT_demo.py
   ├─ logparser
   │  ├─ SLCT
   │  │  ├─ cslct.c
   │  │  ├─ cslct.h
   │  │  ├─ README.md
   │  │  ├─ SLCT.py
   │  │  ├─ __init__.py
   │  │  └─ __pycache__
   │  │     └─ __init__.cpython-39.pyc
```

"SLCT_demo.py" import SLCT from logparser.

```
import sys
import os
# sys.path.append('../')
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
# sys.path.append('../logparser//SLCT//SLCT.py')
# print(sys.path)
from logparser import SLCT
```

When I ran "SLCT_demo.py", this error occured.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\57142\Desktop\Project files\source code\logparser_root\demo\SLCT_demo.py", line 9, in <module>
    from logparser import SLCT
  File "c:\Users\57142\Desktop\Project files\source code\logparser_root\logparser\SLCT\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from SLCT import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SLCT'
```

Here is "**init**.py" of "SLCT".
`from SLCT import *`
Thanks for spending time on my question. Have a nice day!

Comment: pls uncomment `sys.path.append('../')`, and try again. parent folder needs to be in the path, so import can find the `SLCT` directory/module folder.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I have already solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run `from SLCT import *` inside file `x.py`, you need to have the following directory structure:

```
File x.py
Folder SLCT
- File __init__.py
```

In your case, you are trying to run `from SLCT import *` inside file `__init__.py`, which means that you need to have the following directory structure:

```
File __init__.py
Folder SLCT
- File __init__.py
```

And in your case, since this whole thing is already inside a folder named `SLCT`, you're probably caught in your own confusion.

In short, it sounds like you want to simply move the entire contents of file `SLCT.py` into file `__init__.py` (although it's hard to say for sure, because you haven't made the rest of your code visible).

Comment: It works. I do what you have said. Thank you, you really save my day.